# How to manage application secrets in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate

Say I have a C# application in AWS which needs to use a password. I could embed the password in a handful of ways. I'm looking for the recommended way storing and retrieving application secrets.

For example, in Azure, I can upload a certificate and my app can retrieve it securely during runtime. Is there something similar in the AWS world?

Comment: I removed the [tag:azure] tag. No need to tag this as an [tag:azure] question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Even though everyone managing their creds differenly, AWS once wrote an article on how to est leverage S3 + IAM Rolse + Sensetive App Information.

The basic idea is that you store credentials on S3. Launch EC2 instance with IAM Role. Give this role permissions to retrieve a file. And that's pretty much it.

Here is a link http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx610S2MLVZWEA/-Using-span-class-matches-IAM-span-roles-to-distribute-non-AWS-credentials-to-yo